# upload and translate object using Autodesk forge tutorial

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, .net-4.8

A couple of days ago, I started learning Autodesk Forge using their [tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=learn-autodesk-forge), and it worked just fine till [show on viewer step](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/2legged/net).

Today, when I run my app, the browser opens, however, I can not upload or translate an object(file) in the bucket.

[the picture simply shows the buckets I've created and the uploaded files. Only .rfa and cannot even translate them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPP18.png)

[Please check this simple recording for my issue, the video simply shows that I cannot upload the .rvt file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6j14m28r5j26o40/Upload_Issue.mp4)

Comment: Can you give a little more information about what is not working ? Any error message in the inspector ? Buckets created in this tutorial are `transient` so you should not get anything in your bucket after 24h. So if you cannot **upload** files, how do you know **translate** function is not working ?

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I can upload only .rfa files and cannot translate them in the canvas. The first day, I uploaded .rft and it worked just fine but only the first trial.

Comment: When you try to upload a file what happens ? Do you have any error ? Can you open your browser inspector and look for log messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that RFA files cannot be translated. The list of file formats that can be processed by the Forge Model Derivative service can be found here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/.

Comment: Dear all thanks for your reply, I edited my question to upload a video to explain my issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Karim, a couple of notes: (1) note that the upload may take some time in the browser so if you reload the page too soon, you may interrupt the uploading process, and (2) check the browser console to see if there are any errors or warnings; it's possible that there's some issue in the server-side logic, causing the upload process to fail

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue where I was able to upload files to the OSS, however was unable to translate in order for the models to be viewable in the viewer. My solution was to use an active Autodesk Forge account as I found out that my free trial had expired.